# TryParse doesnt work for initial values of if statements

Tags: c#, tryparse

I am using TryParse for the code below, but when I put 1 or 2 the program doesnt continue.

```
int x = -1;
bool noRecords = true;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("1.Add Data");
    Console.WriteLine("2.Show Data");
    Console.WriteLine("0.Exit");
    //x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    if (x == 1)
    {
        Helper.ShowAddMenu(noRecords);
    }
    if (x == 2)
    {
        Helper.ShowDataMenu();
    }
} //while (x != 0);
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out x) ||  x > 2 || x < 0);
```

Comment: Change !int.TryParse to just int.TryParse. TryParse returns true on success, not false.

Comment: @itsme86 see here https://dotnetfiddle.net/6JCoPQ

Comment: instead of complex while loop condition i recommend that break it into sub conditions and put them into while loop then use `break` and `continue` to controlling the loop. it will be simpler for debug as well.

Comment: unfriendly of unkind suggestion - you may want review Operator precedence section of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/

Comment: Your loop is logic is correct for forcing the user to enter a valid value, but you have to move your `if (x == ...)` checks and `Helper` method calls to after the loop. `x` will never be 1 or 2 within the loop.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: "unfriendly of unkind suggestion" can you make it clear? `#1` interacting with user via user interface `#2` input validation `#3` data validation and routing, if you working on a parser/compiler project or a game-engine, with inlining this units it will get messy and buggy very soon.

Answer (score 3):

Your `while` loop is wrong if you want it to continue when you enter `1` or `2`. The order of operations during execution of that expression in your `while` loop will be:

1. You enter the value `1`
2. `Console.Readline()` will return the string `"1"`
3. `int.TryParse("1", out x)` will set x to `1` and will return `true`
4. `!true` evaluates to `false`
5. `x > 2` evaluates to `false` because `x` is `1`
6. `x < 0` evaluates to `false` because `x` is `1`
7. therefore, your while loop is `while(false || false || false)`

EDIT: Given the discussion in the comments below, I believe OPs use case would be best served with a code structure more like the following. Trying to cram it all into the `while` clause is going to be confusing.

```
static void Main()
{
    ShowMenu();
    while (true)
    {
        int x;
        if (!int.TryParse(Console.Readline(), out x))
            ShowMenu();
        else if (x == 0)
            break;
        else if (x == 1)
            Helper.ShowAddMenu(noRecords);
        else if (x == 2)
            Helper.ShowDataMenu();
    }
}

static void ShowMenu()
{
    Console.WriteLine("1.Add Data");
    Console.WriteLine("2.Show Data");
    Console.WriteLine("0.Exit");
}
```

Comment: And, naturally, that expression can be made simpler if the supported values are only 1 and 2. But given the way that OP wrote his code, I am assuming he wants to be able to extend his menu to have more options, hence why I wrote `>=` and `<=`.

Comment: Note that it looks like the actual problem is that OP has no (or twisted) idea of operator precedence - what they likely wanted to write is `while (!(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out x) ||  x > 2 || x < 0))` which is indeed exactly the same as your suggestion.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I was thinking the same thing.

Comment: while (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out x) && x >= 1 && x <= 2); This doesnt works because when i enter -1,5 or "a" the program exits and i want this to happen only for 0. Also when i enter 1 or 2 the : ("1.Add Data"); ("2.Show Data"); ("0.Exit"); appear again.

Comment: @ChristosGrigoriadis The requirements of your program are unclear. When is the "1.Add Data"/"2.Show Data"/"0.Exit" menu supposed to show - only once at the beginning, or again after every invalid input? When you enter a 1 or 2, is it supposed to read another line without displaying the menu and perform the requested action again?

Comment: @ChristosGrigoriadis I updated my answer based upon what I think you're trying to accomplish. In your original code, you were always displaying the menu every time it looped. In order to guard against that, you would have to further complicate your `while` clause. This is one of those cases that's better when separated out clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Change `!int.TryParse` to just `int.TryParse`. TryParse returns true on success, not false.

See here dotnetfiddle.net/6JCoPQ

Comment: That's part of the fix, but it's not the complete fix. If the only change OP makes is to remove the `!`, then the expression in the `while` will evaluate to `true` any time the entered text is an integer.

Comment: while (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out x) || x > 2 || x < 0); This doesnt work because when i enter 0 the program doesnt exit and when i enter a string aaa for example the program stops and doesnt give the options again